# delete and add contenttype or update it?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

There is already a content type whhich is created on RootWeb of a alll Site collections. this Content type has been created programmatically (site scoped feature) so that it gets dynamic guid (id). Now I have to give this content type a static id (guid). the problem is there are too many lists and documents which already used (added) this content type. 
the question is what is the best solution (safe). do I delete the content type from all rootWebs, lists and recreate it (with a static id) and add it again to the lists? or is there a way to update the id of the content type?
I need some code sample (I myself prefer powershell) thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following plan:

1. Create the new ContentType with the right id.
2. Add it to all the site collections that need it
3. Add it to all the lists that need it
4. Change the contenttype of all the listitems
5. Remove the old content type from all the lists
6. Delete the old content type from all the site collections