# How to update a deployed content-type?

Tags: 2010, powershell, content-type, object-model, site-column

I created a content-type and applied it inside a document library.  Now, if I go to the conent-type gallery and delete one of the fields, and then go back to the library and view the available columns, I still see the field I deleted listed as a possible column.

How do I update this to match?  I don't want to delete the content-type ([like in this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32086/delete-and-add-contenttype-or-update-it)); I just want the deployed columns in that content-type to match the current content-type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Next time you perform the changes to the ContentType make sure to push changes to the lists while updating the ContentType.

For now, you might need to perform some clean-up job here, just to make sure the field is deleted from all the lists, with your Custom ContentType. Use the following PowerShell script for clean-up! Vårsegod :)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$site = Get-SPSite "http://your.site.com"
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
{ 
    #iterates through all the Lists        
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $web.Lists.Count; $i++) 
    { 
      $list = $web.Lists[$i];                               
      $MyListContentTypes = $list.ContentTypes                                                          
      if ($MyListContentTypes -ne $null)
      {

         $ct = $list.ContentTypes["You Desired Content Type Name"]                                      
         if($ct)                                                            
         {

             Write-Host "In list Content Type and deleting the field"  $ct.Fields["You Field Name"].Id;
             $ct.FieldLinks.Delete($ct.Fields["You Field Name"].Id)                                  
             $ct.Update()
         }      
       }
    }     
  }
```

**Edit:** How to push down changes to all the Content types via SharePoint Server Object Model:

```
using (SPWeb oWebsite = new SPSite("http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection/MyWebSite").OpenWeb())
{
    SPList oList = oWebsite.GetList("MyWebSite/Lists/MyList");
    SPFieldCollection collFields = oWebsite.Fields;

    string strNewColumn = collFields.Add("MyNewColumn", SPFieldType.Text, false);

    SPFieldLink oFieldLink = new SPFieldLink(fields[strNewColumn]);
    SPContentType oContentType = oList.ContentTypes["Specification"];
    oContentType.FieldLinks.Add(oFieldLink);

    oContentType.Update(true);
}
```

**Edit 2:** Update a Content Type using PowerShell:

```
  Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
    //get the specific Root web
    $spweb= Get-SPWeb "http://your.site.com"
    //get the fields collection
    $fields = $spWeb.Fields
    //get the specific field
    $field = $fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Name of you field")
    //get the specific Content Types from Root Web
    $contentType = $spWeb.ContentTypes["You Content Type"]
    //delete a field from a Content Type
    $contentType.FieldLinks.Delete($field) 
   //add a field to a Content Type
    $contentType.FieldLinks.Add($field)
    //update the Content Type and push changes to the children                                     
    $contentType.Update($true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the script.  I tried the "push changes to the lists" thing, but the columns remain.  If I go to the library and view the content-type, I can still see the column present - just the source is no longer listed.

Comment: It depends how are you are pushing down the changes. When you edit a site content type through the user interface and make a change on a content type settings page, all the settings contained on that page are overwritten during the push-down operation. However, using the object model provides greater granularity in push-down operations. As you make changes to a site content type through the object model, your code is actually making those changes to the in-memory representation of the site content type. Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442695(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Okay, Mr. Mahmood, I'll give that a try and tell you how it goes.  When you say, "using the object model" - do you mean "using" it via powershell?

Comment: Object model mean using the SharePoint server object model. I have updated my response. Alternatively, you can also use PowerShell to accomplish the same task.

Comment: Hmmm... Methinks you posted the second snippet in C#.

Comment: Yes, I have pasted the example from Microsoft's page.

Comment: Mr. Mahmood, if you translate that C# snippet to powershell, I'll mark your answer solved.

Comment: I have updated my post with addtional PowerShell script. Hopefully it will help you :)- Cheers

Comment: Now, how do I do this in Sharepoint Online?